# Datagridview WHERE SQL Error

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, where-clause

I'm trying to automatically fill a *datagridview* upon loading. This is what I have so far

```
 Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Administratot\Downloads\RailwayDatabase2.accdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_shifts WHERE EmployeeName = '" & EmployeeLogin.usersname & "' AND Completed = True", MyConn)
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView2.DataSource = view
```

When I attempt this, I am met with an error reading

> Cannot find table 0.

Comment: use your dataadapter to `Fill` the datatable or dataset

Answer (score 0):

You must fill the dataset first.

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_shifts WHERE EmployeeName = '" & EmployeeLogin.usersname & "' AND Completed = True", MyConn)
da.Fill(ds)
Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help. Keep it *simple*.

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\Administratot\Downloads\RailwayDatabase2.accdb"
Dim MyConn As New OleDbConnection(connString)
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
```

--For error handling, do this

```
Try
'Open the connection
MyConn.Open()

'Fill the dataset
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from tbl_shifts WHERE EmployeeName = '" & EmployeeLogin.usersname & "' AND Completed = True", MyConn)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds)

'Fill datagridview
DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

'Close the connection
MyConn.Close()
 Catch ex As Exception
'Make sure connection is closed
If MyConn.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then MyConn.Close()
End Try
```

And of course, you will put second group of code in *Form_Load* Event.